# Command line argument not being assigned to variable

Tags: command-line

I am trying to make a simple c++ program that takes in command line arguments and uses them to define two ints. The user will type '-f [number] -s [number]' and this will assign int f to equal the number after -f, and int s to equal the number after -s.

At the moment, no matter what numbers I use for the arguments, when I print the results, f is always 0 and s is always 4196288. Could anyone give me a hint as to what is going on here?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int f, s;

    if (argc < 5) {
            cout << "USAGE: " << argv[0] << " -f <number> -s <number>" << endl;
            return 0;
    } else {
            for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
                    if (argv[i] == "-f") {
                            f = atoi(argv[i + 1]);
                    } else if (argv[i] == "-s") {
                            s = atoi(argv[i + 1]);
                    }
            }

    cout << f << endl;
    cout << s << endl;

    }
    return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `strcmp()` to compare char * :

```
        for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
                if (strcmp(argv[i], "-f") == 0) {
                        f = atoi(argv[i + 1]);
                } else if (strcmp(argv[i], "-s") == 0) {
                        s = atoi(argv[i + 1]);
                }
        }
```

and, to parse command line argument, `getopt()` is better choice if it is not your homework.

Comment: Thanks, that finally worked! I just needed to get over that hump to finish the rest of the assignment.